# How to generate a ticket number using given sequence in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need to generate one ticket number using the given sequence which is given below using PHP.

```
1-W1(mandotary).
2-date(yy-dd-mm)format.
3-001-999(each day it will start from 001).
```

One example is given below.

```
e.g-W120160121001
```

I have done the below part which is incomplete.

```
if($_REQUEST['typeOfApp']=="WEB"){
        $ticket_id='W1'.date("Y-m-d").'';
    }
```

Suppose one click event I will generate this ticket number and each day the last 3 digit of this ticket number will start from 001 and up to 999.

Comment: Please paste the code that you have tried.

Comment: Also, have you considered that you may need to issue more than 999 tickets in a single day?

Comment: Do you search for somebody to write the code for you? Or did you already tried something and your code is not working correctly?

Comment: how are you storing the tickets? presumably you need to retrieve the last ticket, get its number, and increment it by one to get the ticket count

Comment: If always i will increment by 1 the ticket will increase more than 999.

Comment: You have a database?

Comment: @satya you're missing my point. in order for anyone to help you, you need to explain how you're storing the ticket numbers

Answer (score 0):

Possible you only need something like this:

```
$ticketnumber = 'W1'.date('YdM' time()).str_pad($value, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

$value is the last ticket key entered for the day. This could be handled by a function to check the last ticket day. If the same date +1 the count. if it is not same date reset the counter.

So lets say you have the following function to generate the ticket code:

```
function ticket_id_generator($ticketnumber){
    $dateline = intval(substr($ticketnumber, 2, 8));
    $value = intval(substr($ticketnumber, -3));
    if($dateline == date('YdM', time())
        return $value++;
    else 
        return '1'; 
}
```

Comment: @ ClearBoth :the id should start from 001 in every day.

Comment: @satya but what you will do after you reach 999 for the day... this code will not help then.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field like id in your table, which stores id number of your ticket booking. and one more query you have to add before inserting the record in the table.

First check that how many records it will have for the same date? and then increment the count of that record and append your dynamic generating ticket code as follows.

```
$ticketnumber = 'W1' . date('YdM'). str_pad(($tempid + 1), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$tempid is the key which is added/started from 1 for the same date.
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP **does not have a mecanism to synchronize a bloc code execution**
2 users can obtains the same ticket number !!
also, you have to store the current ticket number somewhere !!

Personally, i've wrote an open source project that holds ans synchronize the access of variables, you can get it from here in github :[PHP - Synchronized Data Structure Server](https://github.com/Halayem/ANYEM)

And there are other solutions, like storing and incrementing in synchronized flavor using database

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'ticketfile.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Increase ticket number
$current=$current+1;

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

$ticketNum = "W1".date('dmy').$current;

echo($ticketNum);

// This will echo out something like this 
// W121012016001
```

You can also save the ticket number to a database and call last recored     before creating new ticket.

Comment: its then best to save the Unique numer (1-999) into a txt file in server and call it everytime you need new ticket.

I will Post another answer